# Changing MongoDB 3.6 default db path in Windows

Tags: mongodb

I just installed a new MongoDB 3.6 on my Windows machine. Now I'm trying to change the default DB path. So I tried this:

`"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin\mongod.exe" --dbpath c:\mongodb\data`

It worked, but only until I restarted Mongo. Then it was back to usual `c:\data\db`.

I tried to google it, saw some info about changing a mongod.conf file, but I can't find this file in my installation.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `mongod.conf` is definitely what you will need to modify/add. Odds are that if you're not finding it, then it's not created by default and MongoDB instead uses default settings when no such config file exists. Check here for more info: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

Answer (score 4):

Save this script in a Batch File(Mongo.bat) and run it every time:

```
"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin\mongod.exe" --dbpath c:\mongodb\data
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to start mongod with same command everytime:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.6\bin\mongod.exe" --dbpath c:\mongodb\data
```

Or you can create a configuration file and install mongo as a [service](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#configure-a-windows-service-for-mongodb-community-edition).

.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was afraid of. Meanwhile I created manually the .conf file and managed to run mongo with it, but it's still very inconvenient, still has to type in `mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf`. Hoped there could be an easier way to just run `mongod` command and it would run with the config file.

Comment: you can create a mongo service. You will not have to start server again and again.